# Value of tag attribute of html using beautifulsoup in python

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

This is a part of html code, my aim is to find the value of data-autostart in given div element:

`<div class="player" data-autostart="true" data-continuous-play="true" >
</div>`

This is the part of code where I'm stuck:

`a = soup.find('div',{'class':'player'})
state = a.data-autostart`

It gives this error:

`NameError: name 'autostart' is not defined`

```
I tried:> state = a.(data-autostart)
```

But then it gives a syntax error.
Have anybody got an idea how to deal with this kind of names?

Comment: How about `state = a["data-autostart"]`?

Comment: Hey thanks a lot, It worked.